# Adding 3x4 table in popup template using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: popup, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, array

I'm building an arcgis application rendering a csvLayer. I've added a popup template like so:

```
 var template = {
        title: "{SensorTitle}",
        content:
            [
                {
                    type: "fields",
                    fieldInfos: [
                        {
                            fieldName: "DateTime",
                            label: "Date",
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "Temp",
                            label: "Temperature (°F)",
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "Humidity",
                            label: "Humidity (%)"
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "DewPoint",
                            label: "Dew Point (°F)"
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "PM10",
                            label: "PM 1.0 (µg/m3)"
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "PM25",
                            label: "PM 2.5 (µg/m3)"
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "PM100",
                            label: "PM 10.0 (µg/m3)"
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "PollutantId",
                            label: "PollutantID"
                        },
                  ]
              },
         ],
  },

 var csvLayer = new CSVLayer({
     url: numberLayers[0].Url,
     popupTemplate: template,
     featureReduction: {
           type: "selection"
     }
 });
```

Ok so now, I've tried making this filedInfos into a 2 dimensional array, but for some reason I get an error as such:

```
[esri.views.3d.layers.FeatureLayerView3D] #resolve() Failed to resolve layer view (layer title: 'Csv', id: '16b836936eb-layer-0') TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
at dojo.js:1865
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Object.e._getFieldInfoFields (dojo.js:1864)
at Object.e._getContentElementFields (dojo.js:1862)
at dojo.js:1864
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at Object.e._getContentFields (dojo.js:1864)
at Object.e.collectRequiredFields (dojo.js:1862)
at Object.get (dojo.js:1861)
at b.get (dojo.js:295)
```

Now im pretty sure this isnt the proper way to do this. Does anyone have a suggestion on what I may be doing wrong here? Is this even possible with field types?

Comment: If you could post your entire code, that would help to understand why an error is raised.

Comment: First point: From your console error I could deduce that you are using the ArcGIS-JS-API 4.x. Is it right?
Second one; I would double check the field names. It could be that one of them has a typo error.

Comment: @LMokrane unfortunately i cant upload all the code, since I am working on relatively confidential information.

Comment: @Katah yes im using ArcGIS-JS-API 4. Normally this works. Only when I try to make the content field a 2 dimensional array this error comes up. I just want to know if I can add a 3x4 table in the popup template.

Comment: In the title you are using a Field, SensorTitle, which is not described in the content object. Could be that your problem?
Without more information (more code) I guess we cannot help you in a proper way.